# How to get file in source directory as file object

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

This could be pretty easy to do but I'm not able figure it out. There is a script file to be executed in my Flex AIR project under src/scripts/myScript.scpt. To execute this file I need to create the file object of this file but after so many kind of try I'm not able to create the file object. Below is code fragment.

```
 var scriptFile:File = new File('src/scripts/myScript.scpt'); 
 var scriptUtility:File = new File('/usr/bin/osascript'); 
  if (scriptUtility.exists) 
   {
   var processInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
  processInfo.executable = scriptUtility;
  processInfo.arguments = new Vector.();
  processInfo.arguments.push(scriptFile.nativePath);
  processInfo.arguments.push("your argument here");


   var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
  process.start(processInfo); 
}
```

I also tried something like:
var scriptFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('../src/scripts/myScript.scpt');
but in above case if I do something like
scriptFile.nativePath //gives debug path only not my actual script path

In each case I see the scriptFile.exists [always false]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sources aren't published to the appication directory; only resources are. If you want to be able to access that file from the sources, you'll have to explicitly package it into your AIR app.

Comment: As RIAStar said: You need to package the file (event though in Flash Builder newly added resource files are marked for packaging by default, but I don´t know what IDE you are using). And after that, you can simply access it via File.applicationFolder.resolvePath("scripts/myScrips.scpt"); The "src" is not included, it is the applicationFolder.

Answer (score 1):

Only files that are embedded are included in a build. When you do this, the src dir does not technically exist anymore.

So, basically, you do this:

```
[Embed(source="src/scripts/myScript.scpt",mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
public static const SCRIPT_FILE:Class;

var scriptBytes:ByteArray = new SCRIPT_FILE() as ByteArray;
var scriptString:String = scriptButes.toString();
```

That allows you to embed a plain-text file and read it as a ByteArray. It is then translated into a string which you can do with as you please (or you can directly use the ByteArray)

`File` cannot access files created at compile time, as far as I am aware. It is meant for saving files and accessing them later. Generally, you do this by using one of the preset file locations (such as `File.applicationStorageDirectory` which is the location an OS allows for an application to store data)